# Filter ranges within a spill range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of ranges within a spill range:

```
$A$1:$A$5
$A$6:$A$10
$A$11:$A$15
```

Lets say I want to return all cells containing the word `dog` within each range in the spill range (there is a maximum of one instance in each range but I am trying to find the ranges which do or do not contain `dog`).

When using `FILTER` and `INDIRECT` to reference the ranges in the spill range, the formula calculates the range as all the ranges in the spill range as oppose to just the first range, and ultimately returns an error.

The range is not `$A$1:$A$15` as each range acts as a sort of 'category' and some categories may not contain the word `dog`, which is what I am trying to identify.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

From the screenshot below, the aim is to have the `FILTER` formula return a spill containing the `dog` values within each range in the spill range in `C` column.

[image]

Comment: Does your formula return ranges like `$A$1:$A$5` or value from these ranges? Can you put a screenshot of your sheet?

Comment: @Harun24HR Updated the post with screenshot.

Comment: The root problem here is that `INDIRECT` does not handle Arrays of inputs.  (To demonatrate, put `=INDIRECT(A1:A3)` in a cell.  you'll get a spill, but all values will be `#VALUE!`).

Comment: That said, it's hard to see what your larger goal is.  If you explain a bit more of what you are trying to achieve, we may be able to offer an alternative.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Within each range in the C column (spill range), there is either a `dog` value or not. The aim is to return `dog` if the range contains `dog` or return a blank cell if the range does not contain `dog`. I am using a spill range so the output can also be spill and does not require the formula to be manually dragged down.

Comment: If you could illustrate how this would look by way of example (e.g. in column D, I presume?) that would help (manually typing out if necessary so that I can see what it is you're trying to achieve...)

Comment: @JB-007 Column `A`: Every five rows acts as a 'category'. Each category will either contain `dog` or not. Column `B`: Contains a list of ranges for every five rows in column `A`, this list of ranges is spill. Column `C`: Search through the ranges within the spill range and either return `dog` if there is `dog` within the range in the corresponding row or blank cell if there is not a `dog`. Column `C` should be spill. Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Alright thanks @Henry- see someone has posted soln,if that doesn't resolve  then will look at again/more detail with the info you've provided above in hand.   ta, J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(C1#),"Dog"),"Dog","")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your solution does work in this case. What happens if the `dog` value has other words in the same cell (for example, `dog bird`), so we can use a wildcard search. But how can we return the exact value of that cell (`dog bird`, expecting the `dog` values may be slightly different each time, as in there are other words in the same cell)?